# Why is alpha blending not working properly?

Tags: python, pygame, blending

I'm trying to make a simple Pygame application where some colors are blended with colors under them. Here is my code:

**code-listing 1:**

```
import pygame, sys, time
from pygame.locals import *

#define constants
WINDOW_WIDTH = 600
WINDOW_HEIGHT = 600
FPS = 60
    
pygame.init()
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT), 0, 32)
    
alpha = 0
increasing = True
    
while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()

    #fill screen with red
    screen.fill(pygame.Color(247, 25, 0,255))
    alpha_surface = pygame.Surface((screen.get_rect().width, screen.get_rect().height))
    alpha_surface = alpha_surface.convert_alpha()
    surfaceRect = alpha_surface.get_rect()

    #fill surface with orange
    pygame.draw.rect(alpha_surface, (247, 137, 0, 255), (0, 0, 480, 480))
    #fill surface with translucent yellow
    pygame.draw.rect(alpha_surface, (220, 247, 0, alpha), (120, 120, 360, 360))
    #fill surface with green
    pygame.draw.rect(alpha_surface, (0, 247, 4), (240, 240, 240, 240))
    #fill surface with translucent blue
    pygame.draw.rect(alpha_surface, (0, 78, 247, alpha), (360, 360, 120, 120))
    screen.blit(alpha_surface, (120,120))
    
    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(FPS)

    if increasing:
        alpha += 1
        if alpha > 255:
            alpha = 255
            increasing = False
    else:
        alpha -= 1
        if alpha < 0:
            alpha = 0
            increasing = True
```

the code is supposed to make it so the yellow rectangle blends with the orange rectangle and the blue rectangle with the green rectangle. Instead I am getting something that goes from this:

**figure 1:** original state with yellow and blue opacity set to 0%
[image]

to this:

**figure 2:** final state with yellow and blue opacity set to 100%
[image]

As you can see the yellow and blue rectangles not only blend with the red rectangle (screen surface) but they also make a hole to the orange and green rectangle so that we can see the red rectangle through them.

Comment: Of course, the yellow rectangle is draw on `alpha_surface` without any blending. It overwrites the area in `alpha_surface`. and doesn't do any blending with the content of `alpha_surface`. Finally `alpha_surface` is blended to the `screen`. So the yellow rectangle is "mixed" with the background color of the screen.

Comment: @Rabbid76 OK but how do I apply a blending on a draw function (in this case `pygame.draw.rect()`)? here is `pygame.draw.rect()` definition: `rect(Surface, color, Rect, width=0)` as you can see there is no blending flag parameter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to blend different layers, then you have to create different [`pygame.Surface`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.fill)s or images. A Surface can be genrated by loading an image ([`pygame.image`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/image.html#pygame.image.load)) or by constructing a [`pygame.Surface`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.fill) object.

Create a surface completely transparent *Surface* with per pixel alpha. Use [`pygame.Surface.convert_alpha`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html) to change the pixel format of an image including per pixel alphas. Fill the *Surface* with a transparent color (e.g `pygame.Color(0, 0, 0, 0)`):

---

Minimal example:

[image]

```py
import pygame

pygame.init()
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((600, 600), 0, 32)

def transparentSurface(size):
    surface = pygame.Surface(size).convert_alpha()
    surface.fill((0, 0, 0, 0))
    return surface

alpha, increase = 0, 1
run = True
while run:
    clock.tick(60)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False

    screen.fill(pygame.Color(247, 25, 0,255))
    
    alpha_surface1 = transparentSurface(screen.get_size())
    pygame.draw.rect(alpha_surface1, (247, 137, 0, 255), (120, 120, 480, 480))

    alpha_surface2 =  transparentSurface(screen.get_size())
    pygame.draw.rect(alpha_surface2, (220, 247, 0, alpha), (240, 240, 360, 360))

    alpha_surface3 =  transparentSurface(screen.get_size())
    pygame.draw.rect(alpha_surface3, (0, 247, 4), (360, 360, 240, 240) )

    alpha_surface4 =  transparentSurface(screen.get_size())
    pygame.draw.rect(alpha_surface4, (0, 78, 247, alpha), (480, 480, 120, 120) )
    
    screen.blit(alpha_surface1, (0,0))
    screen.blit(alpha_surface2, (0,0))
    screen.blit(alpha_surface3, (0,0))
    screen.blit(alpha_surface4, (0,0))

    pygame.display.update()
    
    alpha += increase
    if alpha < 0 or alpha > 255:
        increase *= -1
        alpha = max(0, min(255, alpha))

pygame.quit()
```